# Отдать файл из сервера на обработку flask

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask

Суть такая, есть flask приложение которое выполняет чтение файлов на сервере где он запущен, это не проблема, но есть одно но, нужно эти файлы перед обработкой отобразить клиенту, что бы он выбрал файл, нажал на него, и он после обработки открылся, в голову пришла такая идея, при переходе в корень открыть autoindex директории, клиент выбирает файл, он отправляется (системный путь к нему) бекенду, обрабатывается, и дальше идет редирект на страницу с результатом...но вот..не могу найти вообще информации по этмоу поводу...

Comment: Не понял в чём проблема, делайте os.listdir и рисуйте html-страницу со списком файлов какую хотите

Comment: Проблема в том, что нужно не просто видеть список файлов\папок, а иметь возможность выполнять навигацию по директориям с целью выбора файла, вот эту возможность предоставляет autoindex, но его прикрутить его к проекту а этой целью  как то не выходит...есть какие - то идеи? или придется писать этот функционал с нуля?

Comment: Не вижу проблем написать его с нуля. Про какой-то существующий autoindex в flask я никогда не слышал

Comment: Спасибо, начал, вот остался скажем так последний вопрос))) могу ли я как-то перехватить событие нажатия на файл? фот загрузил я список файлов\диреткорий в браузер с помощью flask, все выглядит как надо..когда я нажимаю на какой то текстовый файл,  он открывается в браузере, есть ли вообще возможность перехватить это "событие"? или как вообще это делается по правильному? извиняюсь что достаю, в интеренете не могу найти ничего адекватного по этому поводу....(((

Comment: Не вижу проблемы в списке файлов заменить ссылку на файл на любую другую ссылку, какую душе угодно, и обработать факт посещения этой ссылки